# Reversing a list in another list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, reverse

I'm quite new to Haskell and I'm trying to reverse a list. At the same time I want to reverse the lists in that list. So for example:

```
Prelude> rev [[3,4,5],[7,5,2]]
[[2,5,7],[5,4,3]]
```

I know that the following code reverses a list:

```
rev :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rev [[]] = [[]]
rev [[x]] = [[x]]
rev xs = last xs : reverse (init xs)
```

I have been struggling for  while, I have made some additions to the code but it still isn't working and I'm stuck.

```
rev :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rev [[]] = [[]]
rev [[x]] = [[x]]
rev xs = last xs : reverse (init xs)
rev [xs] = last [xs] : reverse (init [xs])
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Point-free, this is just `rev = reverse . map reverse`

Comment: Btw the natural way to write `reverse` by pattern matching is to use a helper function and an accumulating list; first `rev ls = loop [] ls` then `loop acc [] = acc; loop acc (a:as) = loop (a:acc) ls`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have to reverse the inner lists and the outter list. To reverse the inner lists, you can use `map` to apply `reverse` on each element of the list: `map reverse [[3,4,5],[7,5,2]] == [[5,4,3],[2,5,7]]`. Then just reverse the result again `reverse $ map reverse [[3,4,5],[7,5,2]] == [[2,5,7],[5,4,3]]`.

A function that does that is just a composition of `reverse` and `map reverse`, so `rev = reverse . map reverse`.

Here we first reverse the inner lists and then the outter list, but the order doesn't matter and we can do it the other way around: `rev = map reverse . reverse`.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you reverse the inner or outer lists first.

Comment: @Ingo You're correct, that was just a convenient way of talking to make the solution clearer and the thought process clearer ;) But I'll add a precision

Answer (score 1):

The most natural approach is certainly either `map reverse . reverse` or `reverse . map reverse`. It's probably most efficient, however, to interleave the operations explicitly:

```
revrev :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
revrev = foldl (\ acc xs -> reverse xs : acc) []
```

If you want to play code golf, you can write this as

```
revrev=foldl(flip((:).reverse))[]
```

but don't do that.